# Using the data-icon attribute in Jade

Tags: pug

I am not able to use the `data-icon` attribute in Jade. Is there any way to overcome this problem? My code looks like this:

```
span.setting(data-icon="\e65c")
```

Comment: Are you trying to refer to the Unicode character U+E65C?

Comment: Yes. it is dispalying the text not the icon.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted by icktoofay, the "u" is missing in your attribute :

```
span.setting(data-icon="\ue65c")
```